# Form submitting via Post request express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi i am trying to make a small application. I am trying the Post method of submitting a form. When user submits the form i want to save the data and then redirect to a page to show the results. Currently i am not able to Post data although i have used body parser module too for express.js in node. If you could tell that do we need to place the same form action link as the app.post method link. Here's my code:

```
  //html
  <b>Add a New Employee</b><br><br>
  <form action="/addEmp" method="Post">
   First name:
   <input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
  <br><br>
  Last name:
 <input type="text" name="lastname" value="">
 <br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>

  //express.js file:
  var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
 app.use(bodyParser.json());

  app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.render('home');
    });

   app.get('/lastName/Smith', function(req, res) {
   res.render('about_quote', 
    {quotes: employees.lookupByLastName('Smith') 
     });
   });

  app.get('/addEmployee', function(req, res) {
  res.render('addEmp');

});

app.post('/addEmp', function(req, res) {
employees.addEmployee(req.body.firstname, req.body.lastname);
res.redirect('/lastName/Smith');
});// this method is creating problem as it is not posting data.
```

Comment: try getting params in `req.params.firstname` . req.body is for JSON type data. For form submission data is passed in request parameters.

Comment: it still doesnot work. Do i need to add click event for submit button. And should the handler name of post method and form action be the same ?

Comment: try print req object and see if you data comes in any parameter

Comment: no doesnt come.

Comment: can you provide me `employees.addEmployee(req.body.firstname, req.body.lastname);` function call

Comment: module.exports.addEmployee = function (fname, lname) {
  var alpha=0;
 _.max(data, function(data){ alpha=data.id; });
      alpha =alpha +1;
      data.push({id: alpha, firstName: fname, lastName:lname  });

     return _.where(data, {lastName:lname});
}

Comment: Here you go. But the method works fine as i have tried.I have array in which i contain data. and this method adds the new record in it. issue is in form posting action or app.get handler.

Comment: hey update the question, you need to provide every module linked with `addEmployee()`

Comment: so there's a `data` in `addEmployee` provide me that, or make a gist of all related module and a post a link in comment